# Get the last insert id using sync laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to get the last insert id using sync, here is my code

```
$id = $dealer->products()->sync($products);
$dealer_product->payment()->attach($id, $payment_data);
```

here is my DealerProduct model

```
class DealerProduct extends Eloquent {
    use SoftDeletingTrait;
    protected $guarded = array();

    public function dealer() {
        return $this->hasMany('Dealer');
    }

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }

    public function items() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Item', 'dealer_products_has_items');
    }

    public function payment() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('DealerProduct','dealer_product_payments','dealer_product_id');
    }
}
```

and here is my dealer_product_payments table structure

```
id  int(10) 
dealer_product_id   int(10)
paid_at date
expires_at  date
note    text
```

please help me, thanks

Answer (score 6):

`BelongsToMany::sync()` will return an array of ids like this

```
[
    'attached' => [1, 2, 3],
    'detached' => [4, 5],
    'updated' => [6]
]
```

So from that array, you know which ids have been attached